# Pass a data class to another function in order to make a get request - Kotlin from Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

`MoviesData.java` is a Java class.  I'm trying to pass it to another class from `MainActivity.kt` to `MovieRequest.kt`

I'm trying to refactor and have very little idea about what I'm doing.

Here is `MoviesData.java`

```
public class MoviesData {

@NotNull
public final List<? extends Result> results;

public MoviesData(List<? extends Result> results) {
    this.results = results;
}
}
```

This is the piece in `MainActivity.kt` that is probably wrong:

```
val movieType = MoviesData( *****results:***** I don't know what to put here *****)
    MovieRequest(movieType)
```

This is `MovieRequest.kt`. Note that all of the instances of `movieType` in this file are showing errors, so there's likely something wrong here as well:

```
open class MovieRequest(movieType: Array<String>) : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(TmdbEndpoints::class.java)
    val call = request.getMovies(getString(R.string.api_key))

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<movieType> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<movieType>, response: Response<movieType>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                recyclerView.apply {
                    setHasFixedSize(true)
                    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MovieRequest)
                    adapter = MoviesAdapter(response.body()!!.results as List<Result>)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<MoviesData>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MovieRequest, "${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: To make it compile, put `val` in front of the constructor parameter so it also becomes a property. But this won't work at runtime, because Android requires an empty constructor for Activities. The recommended design nowadays is to use a single Activity and multiple Fragments. They can share data through a common ViewModel. But if you still want to use two Activities, you need to pass the object through a Bundle in the Intent extras of the Intent used to launch the second Activity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Comment: Note your class needs to be Serializable or Parcelable to be able to put it in a Bundle. You can look up how to do this in Kotlin. Parcelable is preferable and easily done using the `kotlin-parcelize` plugin.